# DSolve returns its exact input... What am I doing wrong?

Tags: differential-equations

When I input

`sol = DSolve[{D[a[z],z]==I l (Abs[a[z]]^2 + 2 Abs[b[z]]^2 + 2 Abs[c]^2 + 2 Abs[d]^2 +2 Conjugate[b[z]]f g Exp[I h z]),D[b[z],z]==I l (Abs[b[z]]^2 + 2 Abs[a[z]]^2 + 2 Abs[c]^2 + 2 Abs[d]^2 +2 Conjugate[a[z]]f g Exp[I h z])},{a,b},z]`

It just returns

`DSolve[{D[a[z],z]==I l (Abs[a[z]]^2 + 2 Abs[b[z]]^2 + 2 Abs[c]^2 + 2 Abs[d]^2 +2 Conjugate[b[z]]f g Exp[I h z]),D[b[z],z]==I l (Abs[b[z]]^2 + 2 Abs[a[z]]^2 + 2 Abs[c]^2 + 2 Abs[d]^2 +2 Conjugate[a[z]]f g Exp[I h z])},{a,b},z]`

Which is exactly what I put in as my input, so I'm 100% sure I'm doing something wrong, but it isn't clear what...

what I'm trying to get done (in human syntax) is the following

```
da/dz = i*l(|a|^2 + 2|b|^2 + 2|c|^2 + 2|d|^2 + 2b*cd exp(i hz)
db/dz = i*l(|b|^2 + 2|a|^2 + 2|c|^2 + 2|d|^2 + 2a*cd exp(i hz)
```

where :

- i = Sqrt(-1)
- l and h are real constants
- c and d are complex constants
- a and b are complex variables about z

Maybe I'm not supposed to be using Abs[x]^2? Maybe it's just a syntax error somewhere (I'm only a few hours into Mathematica)?

Comment: Is there any reason why you believe that there is a simple solution to this? Not every differential equation can be solved.

Comment: @Szabolcs 

Yes. It's a rather common set of equations found in the field of non-linear optics (parametric amplification thru four wave mixing), with an often cited, although somewhat complicated solution involving lots of exponentials, sinh and cosh functions, and the initial a(0) and b(0).

Comment: Try writing the complex numbers in explicit polar form, get rid of all `Abs`, minimize the number of parameters as much as possible, and provide `Assumptions` on those parameters that could not be eliminated. This is what I would try. No guarantees that it will yield a solution.

Comment: There is no syntax error. What you see means that Mathematica cannot solve this equation.